# RPG Tools (Virtual Board w/ LAN support) (Automatic or Decent Map Generator)

Tags: map-making, tool-recommendation, tools

I am in search of a free virtual board with LAN connectivity. All it needs to be able to do is allow different users connected via LAN to be able to move pieces in real time. A specific user-lock for each character piece would be nice as well as a table displaying whose turn it is, but neither of these capabilities are a necessity. I am also looking for perhaps an automatic generator for caves and dungeons as well as outside areas. If no one has any information about a free automatic generator then a good free map designing software would be great.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but most likely what you'll need is http://Roll20.net

Comment: Welcome to the site! Our FAQ is [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help), and once you have 20+ rep, feel free to join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). It seems your question, or one similar to it, has been asked before, which means you can get answers without having to wait.

Comment: @waxeagle, While I'm a huge fan of Roll20, it uses a round trip to the R20 server rather than being a P2P over LAN application, and it does not generate maps. Fantasy Grounds is closer, as it can be run over a LAN (but also isn't an automatic map generator). I'm not aware of any VTT that _is_ capable of automatically generating maps, actually. (Although there are such generators, such as the ones on http://donjon.bin.sh/)